# running .net core 3.1 app and getting dependent assembly not found error

Tags: c#, .net-core, sqlclient

An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (project.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'runtime.win-x64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni', version: '4.4.0'
path: 'runtimes/win-x64/native/sni.dll'

Project refers to System.data.sqlclient.dll version 4.4.3

Comment: i am also facing same issue 
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Riverbed.AppInternals.DotNetCore.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtime.win-x86.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni', version: '4.4.0'
    path: 'runtimes/win-x86/native/sni.dll'

Comment: Source=https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/612
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.2.1.1\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
  <Content Include="..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.2.1.1\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x86.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content> 
</ItemGroup>